# Javascript Promise, why is reject unhandeled?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have the following code:

```
function validateRole(message, cmdCalled) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    winston.debug('Checking user\'s role');
    Game.findOne({
      running: true,
      'players.id': message.author.id
    }, {
      'players.$': 1
    }).then(function(result) {
      console.log(result);
      if (!result) reject('playerNotFound');
      if (cmdCalled === 'vote' && result.players[0].role.match(/wolf/gi)) {
        message.author.send('Wolves are not allowed to vote!');
        reject('voteDenied');
      }
    }, reject).catch(function(err) {
      winston.debug(err);
    });
  });
}
validateRole(message,'someCommand').then(...)
```

If any of the conditional statements fail I get `error: Unhandled Rejection at: Promise Promise { <rejected> 'voteDenied' } reason: voteDenied`. Why is this not handled by caught? Or is this the wrong way to handle things, would it be better to just resolve with a false value or something and handle result in then() function?

Comment: Kind of an aside: since `Game.findOne` already return a Promise, whats the point of making a `new Promise` to wrap it? What is your new Promise doing that the Promise coming out of `Game.findOne` can't do?

Comment: So I can use resolve('custom response') if needed and use that in .then().

Comment: You mean that you want to use `resolve` outside of a `then`? Otherwise, if you only plan to call `resolve` inside of a `then`, you can `return` instead, since return value of a previous `then` is supplied as an argument to a following `then`. That is, `return Game.findOne(...).then(function() { return "custom response" }).catch(...);` would supply `custom response` to your outer `validateRole(...).then(...);` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you `}, reject).` the returned promise. and as `reject` returnes undefined, there's no way that `.catch` is executed.

+don't use the Promise-constructor antipattern.

Let's clean this up a bit, and you add logging wherever your want.

```
function validateRole(message, cmdCalled) {
  return Game.findOne({
    running: true,
    'players.id': message.author.id
  }, {
    'players.$': 1
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    console.log("error", err);
    //implicitely returns undefined as the `result` into the following `.then()`
  })
  .then(function(result) {
    if (!result) 
      throw 'playerNotFound';

    if (cmdCalled === 'vote' && result.players[0].role.match(/wolf/gi)) {
      message.author.send('Wolves are not allowed to vote!');
      throw 'voteDenied';
    }
  });
  //and after this you either have a promise with a valid result,
  //or a rejected promise containing 'playerNotFound' or `voteDenied`
}
```

or if you want to handle Errors with the request seperately

```
function validateRole(message, cmdCalled) {
  return Game.findOne({
    running: true,
    'players.id': message.author.id
  }, {
    'players.$': 1
  })
  .then(function(result) {
    if (!result) 
      throw 'playerNotFound';

    if (cmdCalled === 'vote' && result.players[0].role.match(/wolf/gi)) {
      message.author.send('Wolves are not allowed to vote!');
      throw 'voteDenied';
    }
  }, function(err){
    //this will catch Errors from `findOne()` but not the errors thrown in the function above
    console.log(err);
    throw 'requestFailed';
  });
  //and after this you either have a promise with a valid result,
  //or a rejected promise containing 'playerNotFound' or `voteDenied` or `requestFailed`
}
```

Comment: @Trax, extended the answer, because on a second thought I don't know wether you intended to handle Errors in `findOne()` as `'playerNotFound'`. So I've added a version where they are handled seperately

Answer (score 0):

At my sight most interesting part of the code is not shown and replaced with `...` into your example.

From your error message is can be seen that `validateRole` returns `Promise` and you're dealing with it at last line of example code. If your `validateRole().then()` contains no handler for promise rejection (and it can't be seen from your example) then this error is obvious - you're not handling promise rejection.

So please either check that you have handler for promise rejection into hidden part of your example or show what do you have here.

Comment: I assumed that catch in the code shown would ... catch and handle any rejection in the code shown.

Comment: You're catching errors **inside** your promise but **generating** rejections of the promise returned by `validateRole`. It is not so obvious at a first sight of course :)